# sending array via ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to send an array of ids for the checked checkboxes via ajax to PHP. I keep getting `Undefined array key "progid"`. when I alert the `progid` in jQuery I got the correct ids. I know it is duplicated question but I really searched a lot and tried a lot of solutions nothing works.

html code:

```
 while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
     $courseName = $row3['courseName'];
     $coursePrice = $row3['coursePrice'];
     $courseId = $row3['id'];
     $programList .= ' <div class="form-check">
                    
     <input type="checkbox" name="course[]" class="form-check-input" id="'.$courseId.'" value="'.$coursePrice.'">
     <label class="form-check-label" for="'.$coursePrice.'">'.$courseName .' price is '.$coursePrice.'$</label>
     </div>';

 } 
 echo $programList;
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var progid = [];
    $.each($("input[name='course[]']:checked"), function(){
        progid.push($(this).attr("id"));  
    });  
                   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: progid,
        success: function(data){
            console.log('success: ' + progid);   
        }
    });  
});
```

php code:

```
<?php
  extract($_POST);
  print_r($_POST);
  echo ($_POST["progid"]);
?>
```

Edit:
when I send the data to the same page it does work and displays the array inside a span , but when I send it to another PHP file it doesn't work it displays the error.

Comment: You're not sending a key, try `data: {progid: progid}`

Comment: I tried this also it doesn't work.

Comment: What does your `print_r($_POST);` show?

Comment: Are you checking any of the checkboxes? jQuery won't send an empty array

Comment: @Don'tPanic  it shows me the other arrays I sent. I send the values of the checked checkboxes.

Comment: @Phil yes I have two groups of checkboxes and I have to check at least one on each of them to proceed to the next page.

Comment: "*it shows me the other arrays I sent*" - that's strange, the code you've shown does not send anything else.  Anyway, the point was, *you* need to look at it, and think about what you're seeing.  It won't include `progid`, because as the first comment here already pointed out, you're not sending that as a key/value pair.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I didn't send the whole page code because it is a little bit long. I posted only the part that cause the error. I also tried to send them as key/value pairs but also I got the same result. maybe I am missing something because I am new to jquery and ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't post all the html, is it possible that your submit event is not disabled with event.preventDefault(); and the ajax is not executing?

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
..
```

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: {"progid" : progid},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success: ' + progid);   
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply .. but still give the same error.

Comment: I updated the answer with e.preventDefault();

Comment: I made the changes but still, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for the array:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var progid = [];
        $.each($("input[name='course[]']:checked"), function(){
            progid.push($(this).attr("id"));  
        });
      
        let stringifyProgid = JSON.stringify(progid);
                       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: {progid: stringifyProgid},
            success: function(data){
                console.log('success');   
            }
        });  
    });
});
```

And in PHP you can get the array:

```
<?php
  $arrProgid = json_decode($_POST["progid"]);
  var_dump($arrProgid);
?>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work. `var_dump` returned null

Comment: @Yamam I edited my answer now. Let me know if it will work

Comment: it didn't work either.

Comment: check the content of progid in console with console.log(progid) before ajax

Comment: when I console.log(progid) inside `$('#submit').click(function() {` it doesn't show anything. but I delete the submit function and write the code inside `  $(document).ready(function () {` then I got the correct ids only when I return to the page after pressing the submit button.

Comment: @Yamam can you try to replace `$('#submit').click(function() {` with `$('#submit').click(function(e) {' p.s. I also updated my answer

Comment: now it show me the array on the console but in php page it gave the same error. I also change the selector to the button name `  $('button[name="checkoutbtn"]').click(function(e) {`

Answer (score 0):

I often do this with Multi Select form fields.

```js
    var progid = [];
    $.each($("input[name='course[]']:checked"), function(){
        progid.push($(this).attr("id"));  
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_post.php",
        data: {
            'progid[]': progid
        },
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
```

Then on the PHP system the $_POST['progid'] will be an array. So all the JSON encoding and decoding others have posted is not needed.